# Search in arrays with javascript on write

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with two input text boxes.
With javascript, I declare two arrays with numbers and names.

number - name:

1 - John

2 - Sarah

3 - Peter

When I write the number on input A, i need the name appears on input B, and if i write the name on input B i need the number appears on input A

Example: I write "Sarah" on input B and number "2" appears on input A

Example 2: I write "1" on input A and "John" appears on input B

Comment: how about just using `name` array and using index as number?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Try to solve your problem first, then google it, then try again a little harder, and finally come here to ask a question (posting every data and failed attempts).. Welcome to StackOverflow BTW :)

Comment: You will get lots of help with legitimate code problems here... but nobody is going to write this for you from scratch and this isn't a `how to` tutorial service either. Do some research into form control events

Comment: Maybe my question is stupid, but I think this is not an "elitist" page (I didnt have to pass any test or anything like that for register...) so for me is a big problem. I tried to solve it, and the real problem is more difficult, and is not the only one. So I decided to ask for anything simpler than to read all the code and try to understand the whole problem. Sorry if I hurted your feelings, Anyways someone had just helped me... ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: Harshal, that is a smart solution!.. but the numbers are not consecutives.. (the numbers i write were just for example). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using pure js you need define a onkeyup event in your input and change the 2 array by a map(hash or dictionary) here the code:

```
<input id="name" type="text" onkeyup="SearchText(this.value)"/>
<input id="value" type="text" onkeyup="SearchId(this.value)"/>
<script>
    function SearchText(val) {
        txt = document.getElementById("value")
        if (val.toLowerCase() in Persons) {
            txt.value = Persons[val.toLowerCase()];
        } else {
            txt.value = '';    
        }
    };

    function SearchId(val) {
        txt = document.getElementById("name");
        for (p in Persons) {
            if (Persons[p] == val){
                txt.value = p;
                break;
            } else {
                txt.value = '';
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Persons is a map:

```
Persons = {
'john':1,
'sara':2,
'peter':3
};
```

this fiddle can help you:

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q2L42sx/1/)